# Android ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException..?

Tags: java, android

So I'm making an Android soundboard app and get this exception and my app crashes when I click the last button of the soundboard app.

[THE CODE]

```
public class newBoard extends Activity {

int selectedSoundId;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    final MediaPlayer player = new MediaPlayer();
    final Resources res = getResources();

    // just keep them in the same order, e.g. button01 is tied to backtoyou
    final int[] buttonIds = { R.id.button1, R.id.button2, R.id.button3,
            R.id.button4, R.id.button5, R.id.button6, R.id.button7,
            R.id.button8, R.id.button9, R.id.button10, R.id.button11,
            R.id.button12, R.id.button13, R.id.button14, R.id.button15,
            R.id.button16, R.id.button16, R.id.button17, R.id.button18,
            R.id.button19, R.id.button20, R.id.button21, R.id.button22,
            R.id.button23, R.id.button24, R.id.button25, R.id.button26,
            R.id.button27, R.id.button28, R.id.button29, R.id.button30,
            R.id.button31, R.id.button32 };
    final int[] soundIds = { R.raw.bengalka, R.raw.cista_psihologija,
            R.raw.da_ne, R.raw.dejo_narkomane, R.raw.dizi_se,
            R.raw.fejslifting, R.raw.fotomale, R.raw.gladan_sam,
            R.raw.jasna_pero, R.raw.jeben_vam_mater, R.raw.kae_ivanisevic,
            R.raw.kae_to_fora, R.raw.kaj_gledas, R.raw.kaj_vi_gledate,
            R.raw.kineza_crnaca, R.raw.kozo_nepodojena, R.raw.marino,
            R.raw.mater_zbrgljavu, R.raw.muha, R.raw.nema_papira,
            R.raw.nered, R.raw.ne_spominji_majku, R.raw.nisam_se_uroko,
            R.raw.odfurati_doktoru, R.raw.pljacka, R.raw.pusi_ke,
            R.raw.sava_sava, R.raw.tebe_i_magazin, R.raw.tog_vani_nema,
            R.raw.za_dom_spremni, R.raw.zrigati };

    View.OnClickListener listener = new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // find the index that matches the button's ID, and then reset
            // the MediaPlayer instance, set the data source to the
            // corresponding
            // sound effect, prepare it, and start it playing.
            for (int i = 0; i < buttonIds.length; i++) {
                if (v.getId() == buttonIds[i]) {
                    selectedSoundId = soundIds[i];
                    AssetFileDescriptor afd = res
                            .openRawResourceFd(soundIds[i]);
                    player.reset();
                    try {
                        player.setDataSource(afd.getFileDescriptor(),
                                afd.getStartOffset(), afd.getLength());
                    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    try {
                        player.prepare();
                    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    player.start();
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    };

    // set the same listener for every button ID, no need
    // to keep a reference to every button
    for (int i = 0; i < buttonIds.length; i++) {
        Button soundButton = (Button) findViewById(buttonIds[i]);
        registerForContextMenu(soundButton);
        soundButton.setOnClickListener(listener);

    }

}

}
```

The exception shows on this line:
    selectedSoundId = soundIds[i];

```
selectedSoundId = soundIds[i];
```

Comment: you have two `R.id.button16` in your `buttonIds`

Comment: you must remove two item

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
final int[] buttonIds = 33 Value   - you have two R.id.button16 in your buttonIds

final int[] soundIds = 31 Value
```

So it is crash.

Comment: I've removed the 32 button but it still crashes

Answer (score 2):

Off-by-two: There are 33 button ids and 31 sound ids. Button 16 is duplicated.

For mapping resource ids and other integers, consider a map, such as [`SparseIntArray`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/SparseIntArray.html).

Comment: I've removed the 32 button but it still crashes

Comment: @MatejDražić Then post the stack trace from logcat.